# session_start error because of configuration php.ini

Tags: php, apache, configuration, web-config

I configured  this in tge php.ini:

```
[Session]
; Handler used to store/retrieve data.
;CHA CHANGED THIS from files to c:\temp
session.save_handler = "C:/temp"
```

But I have an error on my php website when session starts:

```
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot find save handler C:/temp in C:\wiki\inc\init.php on line 154
```

How can I resolve this warning / error?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
session.save_path = "C:/temp"
session.save_handler = "files"
```

Also look at this manual:

[`session.save-handler`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-handler)
[`session.save-path`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path)